# No HTTP Response when direct stream uploading to Amazon S3

Tags: php, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fopen

I currently have a function that grabs an mp3 file from a remote url, and uploads it to an Amazon S3 bucket.

The function seems to work fine in that the file appears in S3, however I'm concerned that while testing this on my local server using a tunnel (ngrok) the page doesn't seem to be returning any HTTP status.

It does return 200 when I download the file locally first, then upload it. As we're dealing with large audio files, I'm trying to make the first idea work in that it's more efficient (I think).

Is there a way to make the page return a HTTP status code and should I be concerned that it currently doesn't?

Here is the code snippet using the V2 Amazon SDK in PHP

```
$config = array('key' => AMAZON_S3_KEY,'secret' => AMAZON_S3_SECRET,'region' => 'us-west-2'); 

$s3 = Aws::factory($config)->get('s3')->registerStreamWrapper();
$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
    'Key'    => 'filename.mp3',
    'ContentLength' => $size,
    'Body'   => fopen($url, 'r')
));
```

Comment: Can you clarify-- are you looking to get a response code from the upload of the file to s3?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I'm looking for a response code from the page where the above code is hosted. I'm not sure whether or not that is a by product of the AWS SDK returning a status code of its own.

Comment: It's still not clear-- what is the question you are asking us to respond to?

Comment: I don't see you storing the putObject response in any variable. Can you please put up the updated code so that we don't get distracted by possible coding errors.

Answer (score 2):

[putObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject) from the official documentation returns a Model Object and will only return the proper Model Object if putObject succeeded

Comment: The put object is succeeding - as in the item is in the s3 bucket.